# What is the etymology of "duffle"?

Tags: etymology, history, historical-change

Where did the word "duffle" (as in "duffle bag") come from, and how did it come to be associated with a bag?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=duffle

Comment: duffle (n.) http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=duffel
    1670s, from Dutch duffel, from Duffel, town in Brabant where the cloth was originally sold. Duffel bag is American English, 1915.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mahmoud koya and Jim have already said in the comments, the word "Duffel" comes from a Belgium town of the same name where the first duffel bags were made using the 'duffel' cloth.

From [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duffel_bag#Etymology)

> Etymology
>
> After the Belgian town of Duffel, which produced the thick cloth from which early duffel bags were made.